# Set an XPath assertion from a CSV file on JMeter

Tags: csv, xpath, jmeter

I'm using **JMeter** for regression tests on Webservice. I'm trying to use an **Xpath** assertion using a **CSV** file to avoid creating several XPath assertions.

Here's an overview of my CSV file *test.csv* (it defines an expected value for each field) :

```
field1,value1
field2,value2
field3,value3
```

And here's my Xpath assertion :

> //Envelope/Body/response/result/data/types/${field)}[text()='${value)}']

Where `field` & `value` are my variables names in my CSV Data Set Config.

When I run my test with 1 iteration, it checks the response with the first line of my CSV. I have to put at least 3 iterations on my thread group to make sure each line of my CSV is used.

I've tried CSVRead function with this kind of Xpath assertion :

> //Envelope/Body/response/result/donnee/types/${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}[text()='${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}']

But I don't know how to loop on it. I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend building your project as follows:

- HTTP Request or SOAP/XML-RPC Request Sampler (which returns XML data)
- Loop Controller (with number of loops matching number of lines in your CSV file

  - Beanshell Sampler (put below code to "Script" area)

    ```
        return ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
    ```

    - CSV Data Set Config
    - XPath Assertion

Beanshell Sampler will just fetch response data from the parent HTTP Request or SOAP Request without re-executing the request so you will be able to re-use response data as many times as required.

- **ctx** - shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) instance
- **ctx.getPreviousResult()** - returns [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance holding information on previous (HTTP or SOAP) request response. Make sure that there is no any other samplers (Debug, Test Action, etc.) in-between HTTP Request and Loop Controller, elsewise you'll get wrong response data
- **getResponseDataAsString()** - self-explanatory

For more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

If you have any problems check out [XPathNameSpaceAssertionDemo](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/xpathnamespaceassertiondemo) project

Comment: It worked ! So if I understand, we are using a BeanShell Sampler to get around the fact we can't put a child controller on a request ? I'll try to count the number of lines in my CSV to use it as parameter in my loop controller.

Comment: Yes, it is used to pass previous result to the assertion no matter how many times it was called. Actually you don't need to "count" lines as you can configure your CSV Data Set config to "Recycle on EOF"  - false and "Stop Thread on EOF" - true, in that case threads will be shut down after CSV file end reached. Check [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more clues.

Comment: Right, I used `"Recycle on EOF" - false and "Stop Thread on EOF" - true` in my CSV Data Set config and checked "Forever" in my loop controler.